# javascript new window - link to footnotes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I found a nice demo online:

[sweet-tabs-jquery-ajax-css](https://tutorialzine.com/2010/01/sweet-tabs-jquery-ajax-css)

, which I used in my project after modification.
But I have a problem - I will have footnotes on each of the pages, the link to which would open in an additional window, say 600px by 600px (as in Kindle).
I wanted to use the script below, but it only opens the window from The first page.

```
<script>       
<!--   
onload=function(){
  for(i=0;d=document.getElementsByTagName('a')[i++];){
   if (d.href.match(/.*hotel\d+\.html/)){
     d.onclick=function(){window.open(this.href,'a','width=740, height=750, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, left=20, top=20');return false}
   }
  }
}

//-- >
<script>
```

I am asking for some simplest javascript that could do this, , or a modification to the above.

Comment: `for(i=0;d=document.getElementsByTagName('a')[i++];){` makes me cringe

Comment: So when you load the tab data, you need to call your code that adds the onclick to the links.

Comment: Javascript that you run in the original page has no effect on other pages that it opens, each page has its own code.

Comment: epascarello - how can  I do it? I don't know at all javascript?